# Как в этом случае скачать файл со страницы сайта с помощью python - requests?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, веб-скрейпинг

Я пробую скачать файл pdf со страницы https://nottka.com/4364-yoshinao-nakada-etude-allegro.html

Если нажимаю на кнопку "Скачать ноты" то файл успешно загружается.

Но если я открою ссылку для загрузки файла (https://nottka.com/index.php?do=download&id=4420) в новой вкладке то вместо загрузки файла попаду на ту же страницу где и был до этого.

В requests пробовал использовать сессию это не помогло.

Также в инструментах разработчика в браузере вижу что перед загрузкой файла отправляется дополнительный POST запрос [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать такой запрос перед тем как запросить файл по ссылке загрузки. Но это тоже не дало результата.

Я был бы очень благодарен за любые подсказки о том куда посмотреть, что изучить и какие нужно пройти шаги, чтобы разобраться как правильно загружать файл с этого сайта. Мне это нужно это в первую очередь для развития, и во вторую уже для парсинга файлов с этого сайта.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import requests

headers = {'referer': 'https://nottka.com/4364-yoshinao-nakada-etude-allegro.html'}
response = requests.get('https://nottka.com/index.php?do=download&id=4420', headers=headers)
with open('4420.pdf', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
```

[В помощь](https://curlconverter.com/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!